# Percent difference display update dynamically with filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Thanks to the help I got from my last question, I was able to create my percent difference column that calculates the difference between each consecutive index for the repeating collection. The problem though I have now is that i've added a filter and I need the percent difference calculation to update dynamically with the filtered results of the ng-repeat table.

Here's the table I have set up, it displays the Index number, Class type, Number, and Percent Difference in a table:

```
<tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="entry in Rankings | filter:myFilter">
  <td>{{ $index }}</td>
  <td>{{ entry.class }}</td>
  <td>{{ entry.num }}</td>
  <td>{{ Rankings[$index].number / Rankings[$index + 1].number * 100 | number : 2 }} %</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Then my filter is set up with a few buttons to apply the filter accordingly:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label ng-click="myFilter = { class: 'Tanker' }" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Tanker</label>
  <label ng-click="myFilter = { class: 'Damager' }" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Damager</label>
  <label ng-click="myFilter = { class: 'Healer' }" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Healer</label>
</div>
```

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to go about making the percent difference column update with the application of different filters? Can I do this within just ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it. The trick is to use the filter also when calculating the percent difference, that way you are reading the next row from the filtered records.

```js
angular.module('test', [])

.controller('Test', function($scope) {
  var numbers = [1,3,5,53,2,552,32];
  
  $scope.Numbers = numbers.map(function(n) {
    return {num: n, class: (['Tanker','Damager','Healer'])[n % 3]};
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label ng-click="myFilter = { class: 'Tanker' }" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Tanker</label>
  <label ng-click="myFilter = { class: 'Damager' }" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Damager</label>
  <label ng-click="myFilter = { class: 'Healer' }" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Healer</label>
  <label ng-click="myFilter = {}" class="btn btn-success btn-md">None</label>
</div>
  
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="entry in Numbers | filter:myFilter">
              <td>{{ $index }}</td>
              <td>{{ entry.class }}</td>
              <td>{{ entry.num }}</td>
              <td>{{ entry.num / ( Numbers | filter:myFilter)[$index + 1].num * 100 | number : 2 }} %</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```